# Automatically index acronyms

Tags: indexing, acronyms

I'm using the acronym package. Is it possible to automatically add an index entry each time an acronym is used?

Comment: The package [acro](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro?lang=de) has the option `index` to add index entries automatically every time you use `\ac`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the `\ac` command so that in addition to its original function it will call `\index`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{acronym}

\let\oldac\ac
\renewcommand*{\ac}[1]{\oldac{#1}\index{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{NATO}{North Atlantic Treaty Organization}
\end{acronym}

Some text about the \ac{NATO}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```