# Is it possible to automatically add an index entry each time an acronym/glossaries command is used in the document?

Tags: indexing, glossaries, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically index acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22570/automatically-index-acronyms)

I am using glossaries package for acronyms (`\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}`). I have a separate .tex file for a list of `\newacronym{key}{label}{description}` and for a list of 
`\newglossaryentry{key}{name=,description=,type=}`. I have used the necessary command for generating index such as `\usepackage{makeidx}`, `\makeindex`, `\printindex`.

I want all the list of acronyms to appear in the index. But i don't want to use the command `\index{}` in the document every time where i use `\acs` or `\acf` or `\gls` or etc, which also looks ugly full of commands. 
Can anybody help/suggest me how to generate index automatically every time i use the command of acronyms or glossary in the document without writing the command `\index{}`?

Comment: Probably this can inspire you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62228/10898

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please be more specific about what should go in the index? Just the acronym or also its extended form? Each occurrence or just the first?

Comment: Lets say, we just put the abbreviation from the acronyms in the index.

Comment: Related: [Automatically index acronyms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22570/automatically-index-acronyms)

Comment: In the link, \package{acronym} and \acro{NATO}{North Atlantic Treaty Organization} command is used in the acronym environment. In my case, glossaries package is used and acronym is an option (\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,section,...]{glossaries}) and the list of acronyms is defined as \newacronym{NATO}{NATO}{North Atlantic Treaty Organization}. In the document, i use \acs{NATO} for acronyms. To generate index, i use \index{\acs{NATO}} which generate NATO in Index. But here i had to use \index{command}. I tired to change follow the link and change \ac to \acs but does not work.

Comment: I believe that this is exactly the same question as [the one @cgnieder linked](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22570/automatically-index-acronyms), and that question contains an answer that seem to be what you are looking for. If I'm work, please explain the difference between your question and the linked one.

Comment: @tohecz The linked question is about the `acronym` package, *not* glossaries.

Comment: This is really NOT a duplicate, as egreg said. Not sure how to notify admins about this, or even if they should be notified....

Comment: I agree. I've voted to reopen since the other question is specifically about the `acronym` package whereas this one is specifically about `glossaries`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@gls@}{\shyam@index{#2}}{}{}
\def\shyam@index#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\shyam@index@aux\csname glo@#1@index\endcsname\shyam@index
}
\def\shyam@index@aux#1?#2\shyam@index{\index{#1}}
\makeatother

\newacronym[longplural={diagonal matrices}]{dm}{DM}{diagonal matrix}
\newacronym{idn}{IDN}{identification number}

\makeglossaries

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\ac{dm}
\ac{idn}

\newpage

\ac{dm}
\ac{idn}


\printglossaries
\printindex

\end{document}
```

However, more work could be needed in case you use other commands for calling acronyms in the text. Without a minimal example covering the needs it's difficult to say more.

Comment: I could really use a solution that works for the whole family of `\gls` macros (e.g. `\gls`, `\glspl`, `\Gls`, `Glspl`, etc.). Since I'm not a LaTeX guru (yet!), I do not understand your trick between the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands. Does your code work only for acronyms? Would it work for the `\gls` commands as well? Thanks in advance!