# Automatically generating an index with acronyms

Tags: indexing, acronyms, makeindex

What I'd like to do is that, every time I reference an acronym, it should be rendered with an `\index{}` using the same value as either the acronym's short or long form.

M(not)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

    \begin{acronym}
        \acro{SE}{StackExchange}
        \acro{TDD}{Test-Driven-Development}
    \end{acronym}

    lorem ipsum \ac{SE} dolor met \ac{TDD}

    % should list "SE" and "TDD", or "StackExchange" and "Test-Driven-Development", or both
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

I tried adding an `\index{}` inside the `\acro` commands (as in `\acro{TDD}{\index{TDD}Test-Driven-Development}`, but that does not work.

One workaround would be using a custom command as below, but I would like to think that there's a better solution (which also works for acronym usage other than just the regular `\ac`).

```
\newcommand{\SE}{\index{SE}\ac{SE}\xspace}
```

Any solutions are appreciated, although those that don't require switching to a different "acronyming" or indexing package would be preferable.

Note: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22570/automatically-index-acronyms) question is indeed nearly identical, but it still requires overwriting each variant of `\ac` (`\acs`, `\acl`, `\acf` etc.) separately. I'm hoping there's a shorter solution, but that might be too optimistic.

Comment: This does indeed target a nearly identical topic - however, it still requires overwriting each variant of `\ac` (i.e. `\ac`, `\acs`, `\acl`, `\acf` etc.) separately. As a computer scientist, I detest duplication, so I'm still hoping for a shorter solution. But thank you regardless :)

Comment: I know you said you'd rather not switch package, but if no one provides a neat solution with `acronym` are you prepared to accept a solution with a different package?

Comment: sure, the other solution is just preferable, not exclusive.

Comment: Sorry, I was too late. The question's been closed. The dup doesn't mention anything about allowing a different package.