# How to automatically index the full name of acronyms from glossaries?

Tags: glossaries, indexing, acronyms, renewcommand

I want to automatically index the full qualified names from acronyms specified with `glossaries` package, when using the acronym in text. I tried with the `acronym` package and this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23855/279450 but it makes up a different index, than I want to have with the glossaries one and it does not use the full name.

I basically want the behavior of

`\gls{cd}`

implicitly and automatically change to

`\gls{cd}\index{Compact Disk}` and/or to `\gls{cd}\index{Compact Disk (CD)}`, if this is simpler,

of an ancronym

`\newacronym{cd}{CD}{Compact Disk}`.

I am not *that* of an TeX expert, but I tried with renewing commands, but it doesn't work so far. I would assume to basically store the full name somehow in a lookup table and renewing the `\gls` commmand with adding the `\index` command to it, but with the looked up name. But I didn't achieved this yet. Is this even (easily) possible as I imagine?